# preserve object ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object in ruby on rails for @user which contains username, password, etc

How can I ensure that the values are kept throughout all views?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set it up as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_user

protected 
  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
  end
end
```

Then in all of controller, since they all inherits from `ApplicationController`, will have the `@user` value set.

**Note:** this will set the @user to nil if the session[:user_id] as not been set for this session.

For more on filters and the :before_filter, check this link out: [Module:ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want some sort of user sustem? logged in and tracking all over your system?

AuthenticatedSystem is something that can help you. there is a lot of documentation out their that will tell you exactly how to setup an environment that uses it. I personally use if for several systems I've made.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ApplicationController`, add your object to the session and create a variable for it. Add a `before_filter` that calls the method that does that.